# Object Has been collected cannot evaluate ContentValues.values.tostring()

Tags: android, android-sqlite, content-values

Can anyone tell me what this is about. Im getting this error when i am adding data in database. its Happening only for a particular row. I tried finding answer or reason over the internet. but in vain. The screenshot
[image: Screenshot while debugging]

```
public void FunSetVisitorDetails(String strResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Get Visitor Details started.");
    if (!strResult.equalsIgnoreCase("NA") && !strResult.equalsIgnoreCase("NI")) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        database.delete("TBL_VISITOR_MASTER", null, null);
            String[] strResultData = strResult.split("#");
            for (int index = 0; index < strResultData.length; index++) {
                String[] strRowData = strResultData[index].split(",");
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("VISITORID", strRowData[0]);
                values.put("MEMBERID", strRowData[1]);
                values.put("TEAMID", strRowData[2]);
                values.put("CATEGORY", strRowData[3]);
                values.put("NAME", strRowData[4]);
                values.put("COMPNAME", strRowData[5]);
                values.put("SPECIALIZED1", strRowData[6]);
                values.put("SPECIALIZED2", strRowData[7]);
                values.put("SPECIALIZED3", strRowData[8]);
                values.put("SPECIALIZED4", strRowData[9]);
                values.put("SPECIALIZED5", strRowData[10]);
                values.put("CLIENT1", strRowData[11]);
                values.put("CLIENT2", strRowData[12]);
                values.put("CLIENT3", strRowData[13]);
                values.put("CLIENT4", strRowData[14]);
                values.put("CLIENT5", strRowData[15]);
                values.put("ASK", strRowData[16]);
                values.put("GIVE", strRowData[17]);
                values.put("TAGLINE", strRowData[18]);
                values.put("EMAIL", strRowData[19]);
                values.put("MOBILE", strRowData[20]);
                values.put("WEBSITE", strRowData[21]);
                values.put("LOCATION", strRowData[22]);
                try{ 
                    values.put("COMP_LOGO", strRowData[23]);// it is happening when adding the logo and image below. there is no exception thrown as well.
                    values.put("PERSON_IMAGE", strRowData[24]);
                } catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                database.insert("TBL_VISITOR_MASTER", null, values);
            }
```

Comment: please post your logcat

Comment: There is no exception thrown to view in Logcat. while debugging i found it written. I have even pressed Ctrl + Shift + f8 and clicked on exception breakpoint. but it doesnt seem to catch it

Comment: Please provide more information about your question. Its not easily understandable. Please post your logcat

Comment: what is the value of strRowData[23] and which type u used in COMP_LOGO column

Comment: The value is an IMAGE in string format. The same goes for strRowData[25].. The Type is TEXT. All the column are TEXT

Comment: @SagarTrehan Sorry Im bad at explaining my issue. let me try to take a screenshot and post that in the question. maybe that will help to show

Comment: WHY DO PEOPLE DOWNVOTE THE QUESTION. I feel its a genuine question.

Comment: Can you print the error? I think you should check if it exists before insert.

Comment: i did not understand @tinysunlight. can you please elaborate more.

Comment: What do you get form e.printStackTrace();?

Comment: It never reached the CATCH statement. it executes perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I guessed the error in saving the image. You need to save the bitmap image for the specific row. So create the column as **`BLOB`** and save the image of **`bytes`** on that.

You will find many tutorials like [THIS](http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/10/insert-and-retrieve-image-into-db.html).